# Webcomponent with internal js and css doesn't show content

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

Learning webcomponents, I tried to make non-trivial ones like this one, wrapping a Leaflet slippy map. Yet, I can't get it to work... Here is my attempt - as you see, there is no map:

[image]

`website-with-webcomponent-online.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <script src="./leaflet-map-webcomponent-online.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Text before Leaflet.
  <leaflet-map></leaflet-map>
  Text after Leaflet.

</body>
</html>
```

`leaflet-map-webcomponent-online.js`

```
(function(){
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
    display: block;    
    .map-root{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 180px;
    }
</style>
<h1>Leaflet web component</h1>
<div id="map" class="map-root"></div>
`;

class CustomLeafletMapWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
        console.log('CustomLeafletMapWebComponent constructed!');
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.loadDependencies();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('CustomLeafletMapWebComponent connected!');

        const mapRoot = this._shadowRoot.querySelector(".map-root")

        // timeout to avoid error "L is not defined"
        setTimeout(function(){

            // initialize the map
            var map = L.map(mapRoot).setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

            // load a tile layer
            L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
              {
                attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
                maxZoom: 17,
                minZoom: 9
              }).addTo(map);
        }, 100);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        console.log('CustomLeafletMapWebComponent disconnected!');
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log(`Attribute: ${name} changed!`);
    }

    adoptedCallback() {
        console.log('CustomLeafletMapWebComponent adopted!');
    }

    loadCssFile(cssfile){
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = cssfile
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(link)
        // // Variation:
        // var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
        // head.appendChild(link)
    }
    loadScriptFile(scriptfile){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = scriptfile
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(script)
        // // Variation:
        // var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
        // head.appendChild(script)
    }
    loadDependencies(){
      this.loadCssFile("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css")
      this.loadScriptFile("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js")
    }
}
window.customElements.define('leaflet-map', CustomLeafletMapWebComponent);
})()
```

In a slight variation, in which I append the script and css file to the document's head instead of the shadow dom, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Change the template's css to:

```
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
        .map-root{
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 180px;
        }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css">
<h1>Leaflet web component</h1>
<div id="map" class="map-root"></div>
`;
```

It does not matter whether you include the leaflet.js into the shadowdom or the document - at least for this example.

```
loadScriptFile(scriptfile){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = scriptfile
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(script)
}
loadDependencies(){
  //this.loadCssFile("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css")
  this.loadScriptFile("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js")
}
```